# Define a custom parser using structopt that changes based on another flag

Tags: rust, structopt

I use *structopt* to parse the command-line arguments to my rust application. The flags in question are the following: `query` (positional), and `case_sensitive` (optional).

```rust
#[derive(StructOpt, Debug)]
pub struct Config {
    /// Query to search for.
    #[structopt(parse(try_from_str = "parse_regex"))]
    query: Regex,

    /// Specify whether or not the query is case sensitive.
    #[structopt(long)]
    case_sensitive: bool,
}
```

What I ultimately want to do is to write `parse_regex`, which builds a regex from the query string argument.

```rust
fn parse_regex(src: &str) -> Result<Regex, Error> {
    let case_sensitive = true; // !!! problem here: how to grab the value of the `case_sensitive` flag?
    RegexBuilder::new(src).case_insensitive(!case_sensitive).build()
}
```

What I'm wondering is whether or not it is possible for a custom parsing function to grab the value of another flag (in this case `case_sensitive`), in order to dynamically parse its own flag.

Comment: Flags are normally passed in arbitrary order, how do you propose do that?

Answer (score 0):

On the command line, flags can normally be passed in any order. This makes it difficult to introduce this kind of dependency in the *parser*.

My recommendation, therefore, will be to introduce a 2-steps processing:

1. Gather the flags, with some pre-processing.
2. Handle interactions.

In your case:

```
#[derive(StructOpt, Debug)]
pub struct Config {
    /// Query to search for.
    #[structopt(string)]
    query: String,

    /// Specify whether or not the query is case sensitive.
    #[structopt(long)]
    case_sensitive: bool,
}
```

And then later:

```
fn build_regex(config: &Config) -> Result<Regex, Error> {
    RegexBuilder::new(&config.query)
        .case_insensitive(!config.case_sensitive)
        .build()
}
```

Comment: That's a totally valid way, but I was wondering if it was possible to do that inside of the `Config` struct in one go.

Comment: @jonathanGB: I very much doubt so given the amount of complexity this would introduce (a dependency graphs between fields) for such a minor gain.